# Instruct .pro file to write a new file on deployment/installation

Tags: linux, qt, installation, project, qmake

I have a .pro file for my project, containing the following:

```
APP_DISPLAY  = "My Libraries"
APP_NAME     = "MyLib"
VERSION      = 1.02.0002
ORG_NAME     = "My Org"
ORG_DOMAIN   = "www.myorg.com"
PACKAGE_NAME = $${APP_NAME}.mylibraries.myorg# used for opkg/ipk

TARGET = mylibraries
target.path += /usr/bin/myapp/

DISTFILES += \
    Main/QtPlugins/libraries/*.so \
    Main/QtPlugins/testPlugins
```

The project creates an ipk which installs (using opkg) a bunch of libraries (.so files) in a certain location.

However, I need to get that `VERSION` parameter somewhere on the system, because another application needs to know the version of this package for use with an automated updater.

Is there something I can put in the .pro file which will cause it to create a simple file containing the value of `VERSION` ? Even if the file was empty and the version was in the filename that would do, though I'd rather have a file with the version in the contents.

I also looked at writing using the postInst script, which runs automatically after installation. From this script I can easily have it create a file, but I don't know how I would get it to access the `VERSION` value from the .pro file - so info on how to do this would  be just as good.

Comment: Does `system("echo $$VERSION > version.txt")` do what you want?

Comment: @JarMan - no afraid not, that writes it during the build, whereas I want to write it during installation (i.e. when running `opkg install`) - I tried putting the same statement (without `system()` into the `postInst` script, but of course that has no idea what `$$VERSION` is.

Comment: Maybe try writing it to an environment variable?